# Cannot write to USB drive in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

My company computer is Windows 7, anytime I try to use a third-party software program to write to a removable USB flash drive, I get an error below.
"`Cannot write to Drive F:. Access is denied.`"

Whatever I used USB Thumb or SD through SD card reader, I got the same problem.  However, all would be written with "*Window Explorer*".

I am administrator of this computer. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

**For example :**
WinHex open a USB thumb
→ error `#21 cannot write to drive F:`

But same USB thumb drive and same version WinHex in my home computer don't have problem (WinXP).

Comment: Forget the home computer for a while and clarify this, **Are you able to write to USB disk when not using third party software ?**

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Yes, I am able to write with "Window Explorer"

Comment: Have you tried running the program as an administrator?

Comment: Right click on the program and select run program as administrator, even if your account is an administrator type youmay still have to do it!

Comment: @Stack learner : yes, I right click "run as administrator".